# How did Masih ad-Dajjal lose his eye?

Tags: islam, eschatology

In Islamic eschatology, [Masih ad-Dajjal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masih_ad-Dajjal) is a one eyed false messiah:

> Narrated 'Abdullah bin 'Umar:
>
> Allah's Apostle said. "While I was sleeping, I saw myself (in a dream) performing Tawaf around the Ka'ba. Behold, I saw a reddish-white man with lank hair, and water was dropping from his head. I asked, "Who is this?' They replied, 'The son of Mary.' Then I turned my face to see another man with a huge body, red complexion and curly hair and blind in one eye. His eye looked like a protruding out grape. They said (to me), He is Ad-Dajjal." The Prophet added, "The man he resembled most is Ibn Qatan, a man from the tribe of Khuza'a. "
>
> <sub>Source: [Translation of Sahih Bukhari, Book 88: Afflictions and the End of the World, Volume 9, Number 242](http://www.usc.edu/org/cmje/religious-texts/hadith/bukhari/088-sbt.php#009.088.242)</sub>

His missing eye appears to be significant, as it betrays his true nature:

> Narrated Anas:
>
> The Prophet said, "No prophet was sent but that he warned his followers against the one-eyed liar (Ad-Dajjal). Beware! He is blind in one eye, and your Lord is not so, and there will be written between his (Ad-Dajjal's) eyes (the word) Kafir (i.e., disbeliever)." (This Hadith is also quoted by Abu Huraira and Ibn 'Abbas).
>
> <sub>Source: [Translation of Sahih Bukhari, Book 88: Afflictions and the End of the World, Volume 9, Number 245](http://www.usc.edu/org/cmje/religious-texts/hadith/bukhari/088-sbt.php#009.088.245)</sub>

Do we know how Masih ad-Dajjal ended up with such an obvious giveaway?

Answer (score 5):

The word 'one-eyed' is not to be taken literally

Allah says in the Holy Qur'an

> "whoever is blind in this world will be blind hereafter".

Blindness here evidently means spiritual blindness. Thus the word under discussion will mean that Dajjal will have no spiritual sight, although his worldly sight will be very sharp; and along with it, he will discover such subtle methods resulting in such wonderful performances, that he will almost appear as one claiming divinity. 
But he will have no spiritual vision whatsoever.<sub>[Muhammad Ali. (1992) The Antichrist and Gog and Magog Archived 1 July 2018 at the Wayback Machine, Ohio: Ahmadiyya Anjuman-i Ishāʿat-i Islām](https://web.archive.org/web/20180701133728/http://aaiil.org/text/books/mali/gog/antichristgogmagog.pdf)</sub>

The Dajjal's (antichrist) blindness is supposed to be a obvious giveaway. The Dajjal has many powers and will try to convince people he is Allah.

[Ubadah ibn As-Samit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubada_ibn_as-Samit) wrote:

> The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said,
>   “Verily, I have told you so much about the False Messiah that I am
>   afraid you will not understand. Verily, the False Messiah is a short
>   man, pigeon toed, curly haired, with one eye that is sightless,
>   neither protruding nor sunken. If you are confused about him, then
>   know that your Lord does not have one eye.”

Comment: Your source is Ahmadiyya. They are not considered muslims, neither through the sunnah nor through the Amman Message. There's no indication that any of it is symbolic, mainstream scholars such as An-Nawawi took it literally(see Sharh al-Nawawi li Saheeh Muslim).

Comment: Analysis of myth, and religious literature in the context of myth, involves symbolism.  Good answer.